# Best strategy for UK visa for a school trip (travelling alone or accomanpied child)?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, children

I'm a teacher from a school in mainland Europe trying to arrange a trip to the UK with a Russian student who already has an accompanied child visa for the uk. I recognise you have have up to 2 endorsements - both of these are his parents. As his teacher they have signed power of attorney to the school but I don't think that will cover it if I were to show up with this.

This leaves me with the following suggestions to the parents:

- apply for accompanied child visa again with me as the named adult BUT will that invialidate the existing endoresments meaning that the existing visa gets binned and they'd not only have to apply for THIS visa for me but then ANOTHER visa as soon as they wish to travel to the UK with him again?
- apply for travelling alone .. but the information on the adult being stayed with will be me

  - the name and date of birth of the person that you will be staying
    with (me)
  - an address where you will be living (the hotel)
  - details of your relationship to the person who’ll be looking after you (his teacher)
  - consent in writing so they can look after you during your stay in the UK (written consent from me)

<-- but this latter option seems a little weird as I would actually be accompanying him on the flight.

.. or some other solution I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Have you read this guidance? https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/school-children-travelling-to-the-uk-as-part-of-a-school-group

Comment: @MJeffryes wow that has the potential to be *massively* helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to comment from @MJeffryes

https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/school-children-travelling-to-the-uk-as-part-of-a-school-group/school-children-travelling-to-the-uk-as-part-of-organised-school-groups

> School children, who are visa nationals, and, are resident in an EEA
>   country do not need a visa if visiting or transiting the UK as a
>   member of an organised school group.
>
> To qualify school children must:
>
> ```
> be accompanied by a teacher
> have their names included on the officially approved ‘List of Travellers’ form.
> ```
>
> Schools must get the ‘List of Travellers’ form from the foreign
>   ministries of the EEA country where the school party is travelling
>   from. The European Commission website provides contact details.

... now there's just the next thing to sort which is the fact that the planned trip straddles the possible UK crash out date! But that's another story ;)